# EDR Detection For A Clear Password For Websphere Password

Tags: db2, websphere, password-encryption, wsadmin

I detect through EDR that there's clear creds for websphere credentials as the following.

```
cmd.exe "PATH\IBM\Websphhere\Appserver\bin\stoserver.bat" "server1" -username wasadmin -password ClearTEXT >> "\\PATH\\server.log"
```

So my Question Is:

How to encrypt the password in the command line at the end user so i can see it hashed or in an encryption way from my side at [EDR] logs .

As i can't find a proper [suitable with my environment] way to encrypt the password of the WebSphere admin user in the command line

Expecting to find a way to encrypt password in the command line so i can see it hashes at the EDR .

Comment: with MS-windows cmd shell there is no ability to encrypt passwords on the command line. Most people arrange to avoid any passwords on command-ines. Study the docs for your version of the "stoserver.bat" to see if it is possible to collect credentials from encrypted-files instead of command-line.